# Can I use the same schema.org markup on an AMP website that I do on my normal site?

Tags: seo, schema.org, amp

I am working on project which have both amp as well as non-amp website. I want to implement schema.org. I have articles on non-amp website having schema as per schema.org guidelines. Can I use the same schema for AMP pages?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can implement structured data on AMP pages as well, in fact, it is a highly recommended method from the Google.

AMP pages that have structured data can appear in a carousel of stories in search results. Without structured data, AMP pages can appear only as standard blue links in Google Search results.

Visit for more info: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles